# Why is the output not returning the value?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the HTML code below:

[image]

But when I enter some text the output is this:

[image]

Why is it not showing the name entered?

PS: I am an absolute beginner in JS. Please bear with me. Thank you!

Comment: Try using `name.value` to get the text value of the `name` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is because you are printing the html element and not it's value.

To get the value use:

```
var name = document.getElementById('NAME').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `document.getElementById("NAME")` to `document.getElementById("NAME").value`

Answer (score 1):

Upate your function sayWelcome() with code:

```
function sayWelcome()
{
  var name = document.getElementById('NAME').value;
  alert("Welcome " + name+"!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you didn't mention about the value of the field

Try this to solve the problem

```
  var name = document.getElementById('NAME').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` returns an `HTMLElement` - in your case `HTMLInputElement` object because a textbox is an input element. The `value` property can then be used to set or get the input of a specific input element.